# Does the Healing skill stack with Innervate and+or Encroaching Darkness?

Tags: torment-tides-of-numenera

We have this skill called Healing. The description says: "+5 bonus points per level healed when any healing ability or item is used. Inability confers -2 penalty to healing."

If I use Innervate, will I heal 11 points?

[image: Innervate description]

If I use Encroaching Darkness, will I heal 13 points?
[image: Encroaching Darkness description]

Or will it work+stack with other specific abilities only?

Comment: If the descriptions are correct, it certainly seems to have the effect you're assuming it has. But it also seems like you are in the perfect position to try it out, so, why are you asking it here :) ?

Comment: @Joachim, I just leveled up, there are hours of story before my next save + gain control of my character (The Sorrow attack to the Sanctuary of Miel Avest) and, most important, so people in the future have that answer at hand before leveling up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested and it stack with Encroaching Darkness, Innervate and Sprayflesh.